# PL/SQL base conversion without functions

Tags: oracle, plsql, binary, base-conversion

Is there any way to convert decimal to binary, or binary to decimal, in Oracle 10g without having to first define a function?  I have limited database access (SELECT only) and all the solutions for this I've found online seem to involve `CREATE FUNCTION`, which does not work for me.

Answer (score 2):

If hexadecimal is good enough, then TO_CHAR and TO_NUMBER can work:

```
SQL> select to_char(31, '0x') from dual;

TO_
---
 1f

SQL> select to_number('1f', '0x') from dual;

TO_NUMBER('1F','0X')
--------------------
                  31
```

You may be able to use the `RAWTOHEX()` and `HEXTORAW()` functions to make the hex to binary transition as well.

Answer (score 1):

Frank Zhou who specializes in gnarly SQL puzzlers has devised a pure SQL solution for this problem.  You can find it on [his OraQA site](http://oraqa.com/2008/02/29/how-to-convert-decimal-base-ten-number-to-binaryoctalhex-in-sql/).  But be warned: it is *really* gnarly.

**update**

Original link to OraQA is broken: [The Wayback Machine has an archived version here](http://web.archive.org/web/20150104004825/http://oraqa.com/2008/02/29/how-to-convert-decimal-base-ten-number-to-binaryoctalhex-in-sql).

Comment: That is truly twisted. I like it. ;)

Comment: The link is dead. Solution might have been the same as this one - https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:::YES:RP:P11_QUESTION_ID:7041297073738

Comment: @jva - thanks for the tip.  I have added an archived link.  FZ solution is more complicated, because he doesn't just do Hexadecimal.

Answer (score 0):

Can you execute PL/SQL in an SQLPlus script like this:

```
declare
    procedure bin_2_dec(/*some parameters here*/) is
    begin
        /*do computation and print result*/
    end;
begin    
    bin_2_dec('11110000');
end;
/
```

I'm not sure but I don't think the function will be created permanently in the database, I think it will only exist temporarily for the duration of the script so this *might* work. It's worth a shot, right? ;)

Or if that doesn't work, you could `SELECT ... from dual` to convert, though that will probably be awkward and will only work if you know the number of digits - maybe (I'll try to throw it together if I can get a few minutes, and if it's possible).

Comment: Just to be clear: we cannot use functions declared like this in  SQL statements embedded inb the anonymous block.  That hurls PLS-00231, because we can only use SQL-declared functions in SQL statements.

Comment: No, I imagine this function would not be usable from a SELET statement, but the function/procedure *is usable from PL/SQL in the SQLPlus script* . I don't know if PL/SQL in a script is a viable solution or not.

Answer (score 0):

A crude, but straight-forward solution for decimal-to-binary:

```
SELECT REPLACE
       (REPLACE
        (REPLACE
         (REPLACE
          (REPLACE
           (REPLACE
            (REPLACE
             (REPLACE
              (REPLACE
               (REPLACE
                (REPLACE
                 (REPLACE
                  (REPLACE
                   (REPLACE
                    (REPLACE
                     (REPLACE
                      (TO_CHAR (100,'FMxxx'),
                       '0','0000'),
                      '1','0001'),
                     '2','0010'),
                    '3','0011'),
                   '4','0100'),   
                  '5','0101'),
                 '6','0110'),
                '7','0111'),
               '8','1000'),
              '9','1001'),
             'A','1010'),
            'B','1011'),
           'C','1100'),
          'D','1101'),
         'E','1110'),
        'F','1111')
  FROM DUAL;
```

Binary-to-decimal would be trickier.  You might be able to use `connect by` to split the string into 4-character segments, convert them in a similar fashion, then concatenate them back together (a second `connect by` using `SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH`?), but that's a little too tedious for me to work out tonight.

---

On second thought, here's the Binary-to-decimal solution (I'm a sucker for `connect by` problems):

```
SELECT     TO_NUMBER(
               REPLACE (
                   SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH (octet, '!'), 
                   '!', ''),
               'xxxxxx')
      FROM (SELECT     CASE SUBSTR
                                (LPAD (a,
                                       CEIL (LENGTH(a)/4)*4, '0'),
                                 (LEVEL-1)*4+1, 4)
                          WHEN '0000'
                             THEN '0'
                          WHEN '0001'
                             THEN '1'
                          WHEN '0010'
                             THEN '2'
                          WHEN '0011'
                             THEN '3'
                          WHEN '0100'
                             THEN '4'
                          WHEN '0101'
                             THEN '5'
                          WHEN '0110'
                             THEN '6'
                          WHEN '0111'
                             THEN '7'
                          WHEN '1000'
                             THEN '8'
                          WHEN '1001'
                             THEN '9'
                          WHEN '1010'
                             THEN 'A'
                          WHEN '1011'
                             THEN 'B'
                          WHEN '1100'
                             THEN 'C'
                          WHEN '1101'
                             THEN 'D'
                          WHEN '1110'
                             THEN 'E'
                          WHEN '1111'
                             THEN 'F'
                       END AS octet,
                       LEVEL AS seq,
                       CEIL (LENGTH(a)/4) AS max_level
                  FROM (SELECT '101010101010101010' AS a
                          FROM DUAL)
            CONNECT BY LEVEL <= CEIL(LENGTH(a)/4))
     WHERE LEVEL = max_level
CONNECT BY PRIOR seq = seq-1
```

This solution only works for one row at a time as currently written.  To make it work with multiple rows, you'd need to add some sort of unique identifier to the outermost `connect by`.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying this in Oracle using `CONNECT BY` to covert decimal to binary in a simple `SELECT` statement. Finally got the desired output. You can use the below, it is working fine.

```
WITH INPUT AS  
(SELECT &N AS X FROM DUAL)
SELECT SUM(MOD(FLOOR(X*POWER(0.5,LEVEL-1)),2)*POWER(10,LEVEL-1)) AS 
OUTPUT FROM INPUT CONNECT BY POWER(2,LEVEL-1)<=X;
```